# Using mixins in bootstrap 3 to avoid unsemantic markup for layout structure

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm relatively new to both bootstrap and less and this is a test run. The goal is to take the bootstrap classes and turn them into simple and semantic classes using less. I keep getting error messages saying that .col-sm-12 and .col-md-8 are undefined.

How do I do resolve this issue.

```
    /*less styles file*/

@import "bootstrap.min.css";

@boom: #ea7000;

@screen-sm: ~"(min-width:768px)";
@screen-md: ~"(min-width:992px)";
@screen-lg: ~"(min-width:1200px)";

.tim    {
    height: 200px;
        @media screen, @screen-sm   {
            background-color: black;
            .col-sm-12;
        }
        @media screen, @screen-md{
            background-color: @boom;
            .col-md-8;
        }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm way off but the primary goal is to have one simple class that substitutes the multiple classes that Bootstrap forces me to use.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You should import the `bootstrap.less`file. So, download the full bootstrap project, and copy out the less folder. It contains everything. And then put the less folder in your project. Also make sure to add the less.js file to your project if you want to get your less compiled while your working. Look at lesscss.org for more information. And also make sure that you have a local server like mamp or xamp, because you can't see the results if you are just serving static html from file:// ....

[image]

In your custom less file do something like this:

**custom.less**

```
@import "../less/bootstrap.less";

 section {
    .make-row();
}
.left-navigation {
    .make-sm-column(3);
}
.main-content {
    .make-sm-column(9);
}
```

**html**

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="css/custom.less">
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/1.4.1/less.min.js"></script>
</head>
<section>
<div class="left-navigation">
</div>
<div class="main-content">
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: I will definitely try that. That might be the fix I need.

Comment: i just added some edits, make sure you are serving off of a local server, otherwise it wont work

Comment: thank for the info I will def download the entire project. I downloaded the project from HTML5 boilerplate. Do I still have to download the less files from getbootstrap?

Comment: if it contains the less folder with all the less files then you dont need to download the project, otherwise you need to download the project to access the less files in the less folder.

Answer (score 9):

If your goal is to make beautiful semantic HTML using Bootstrap, I would suggest you give up now or face insanity. I discovered quite painfully that trying to get semantic markup out of BS 2 is impossible. It requires complex nesting rather than a mix-in architecture to achieve what you want, even if you use less or sass. Also, the classes and ids are referenced by its JavaScript components so it can't be changed. You can create your own styles, but it defeats the purpose of using a framework like BS.  I can't comment on version 3 and would love to hear other people's experiences with it.

Comment: Interesting comments.  I've just started using bootstrap and the first thing I thought was "isn't this non-semantic CSS class naming usually considered _BAD_ practice?".  I was toying with the idea of using LESS mixins to make semantic classes that inherit from bootstrap, but thought against it on the grounds that it was probably going to take more time that it would to not use bootstrap and write all the CSS from scratch.  Your answer has helped validate my approach so thanks!

Comment: I've found BS3 to be just as painful to get semantic markup. Even when you rely entirely upon mixins, you often need to add extra elements to follow the golden path "Container > Row > Col > Row > Col" nesting structure or face issues with nothing actually lining up on the grid.

Comment: Apologies, I know this is an old thread, however as this is found on Google I definitely disagree with the statement "You can create your own styles, but it defeats the purpose of using a framework like BS." I always implement my own styles aside BS and Twitter actively encourages you to customize their framework to suit your needs.

Comment: The point of a framework is so that you have a set of reusable components that can be easily maintained over time. When you make modifications to their source code, you've cut your source code off from the stream of framework update releases. You will have to manually merge the changes which can be very difficult. Non trivial websites will require updates to the HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I've found it useful to just import a few select less files to avoid the multiple class confusion you get with Bootstrap grids, like this.

**CSS**

```
@import "less/variables.less";
@import "less/mixins/grid-framework.less";
@import "less/mixins/grid.less";

.firstItem {
    .make-xs-column-offset(3);
    .make-xs-column(1);
    .make-sm-column-offset(3);
    .make-sm-column(1);
    .make-md-column-offset(3);
    .make-md-column(1);
    .make-lg-column-offset(3);
    .make-lg-column(1);
}
.middleItem {
    .make-xs-column(1);
    .make-sm-column(1);
    .make-md-column(1);
    .make-lg-column(1);
}
.lastItem {
    .make-xs-column(5);
    .make-xs-column(5);
    .make-xs-column(5);
    .make-xs-column(5);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="firstItem">
    first item stuff
</div>
<div class="middleItem">
    middle item stuff
</div>
<div class="middleItem">
    middle item stuff
</div>
<div class="middleItem">
    middle item stuff
</div>
<div class="lastItem">
    last item stuff
</div>
```